# Matching variables with spaces using cucumber anonymous expresion

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

With a feature containing a Scenario Outline and an Example table like:

```
Feature: Demonstrate Issue
Scenario Outline: Parameters with spaces don't match
    Given a variable containing <var>

    Examples:
        | var         |
        | No_Spaces   |
        | Some Spaces |
```

I'm struggling to match the `<var>` in my steps using [cucumber expression](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/) with cucumberjs.

I know that the `{string}` parameter type requires double quotes rather than the angular brackets, but I expected the anonymous type to match:

```
Given('a variable containing {}', function(expectedVar) {
   return true;
});
```

But it doesn't.

I know I can use the regex option:

```
Given(/^a variable containing (.*)$/, function(expectedVar) {
   return true;
});
```

I would just like to know where I'm going wrong in my use of the anonymous parameter type.

Comment: Anonymous expressions were introduced in `6.2.0` of `cucumber-expressions`. Looks like it hasn't been propagated to `cucumber-js` yet. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/package.json#L156

Comment: But for clarity you'd be better of using `Given a variable containing "<var>"` and capture it with `a variable containing {string}`

Comment: Thanks that's just what I was looking for. My only concern with that is that the gherkin starts to look non standard. I believe our other projects just use <var>, so I don't want to add the ambiguity and make people decide to use "<var>" or <var> depending on what project the gherkin is for.

Comment: I think you should always quote your values when theyr'e not identifiers. When they're identifiers you can use `{word}` and forgo the quotes.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice, there doesn't seem to be much content around this so its good to get road tested opinions.